# Is there a JDiff from Java 6 to Java 7?

Tags: java, java-7

There is one for [Java 1.4 to Java 5](http://javadiff.sourceforge.net/jdiff/reports/j2se142_j2se150b1/changes.html). Did somebody set up a version for Java 6 to Java 7?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no. Would be great if JDiff Project makes it.

Comment: this could be comment.

Comment: Why comment? the answer is no...

Comment: If it is not an answer then add your comment below the question(Need sufficient reputation for this) BUT not as an answer.

Comment: The question is closed. And it's my answer because is valid. If you don't like it it's your problem.